# Java - Is it possible to have two components on the same side with GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout

[image]

Is it possible to have the "Save note" button under the "Create note" button using GridLayout? If not, what layout should I be using? dataPanel contains both text fields and both labels. buttonPanel is the save note button and namePanel is the create note button.

```
    container.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    container.add(namePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible! Simply define a grid layout with 2 rows and 3 columns each:
 - first column will contain the labels
 - second column will contain the text boxes
 - 3rd column will contain the buttons

Also, why are you using the `BorderLayout` constants when adding to the `GridLayout`? With `GridLayout` once you have decided on the rows/columns simply add them in the order you want them to be layed out in the "grid" from left to right, top to bottom. So in the above example you will do something like this:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel( new GridLayout(2,3) );
p.add( /* enter the desired note label */ );
p.add( /* note name here text box */ );
p.add( /* create note button */ );
p.add( /* enter a new note label */ );
p.add( /* note text here text box */ );
p.add( /* save note button */ );
```

Comment: yes, but just in the case that into row 2nd. in Grid 3rd. should be some a JComponent that is added to JPanel but it isn't visible, same for row 3rd Grid 1st.