# Java swing - creating text field on button's place

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

When specific action is performed, I want to replace button with text field. I know that I have to call `button1.setVisible(false);` but I don't know how to create text field on the exact same place. I am using NetBeans designer, if you can give me a hint, how to add 2 components at same place, and switch between then, something like switching between layers in photoshop, if something like that is possible, would be great. Thanks

Comment: Which layout are you using? If you are using GridLayout then I highly recommend checking this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937229/java-is-it-possible-to-have-two-components-on-the-same-side-with-gridlayout) out. Good luck.

Comment: You may use a `JPanel` with `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for almost your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as see in this [short example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

[image] [image]